# Site URL For Facebook App

Tags: facebook

I have created an app for our Facebook page, and I have all the correct info, but Facebook is telling me that I haven't specified a Site URL or a Mobile Site URL. I cannot seem to find where to enter this info in order to get the app up and running on our page. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your app's settings at https://developers.facebook.com/apps (on the main page of settings for the app)

Answer (score 19):

Go to your [Facebook App](http://developers.facebook.com/apps/). In the Settings, click the "Add Platform" button under the Basic settings. A popup will open asking where you are presenting your app.  I chose Website, and it asked for my Site URL and Mobile Site URL.

Comment: You can't add the App Domain without the Site URL. But, the error you get in the App Domain field when the Site URL is undefined doesn't say where to find the Site URL. FB should make this simpler. Add a message to the App Domain error or something. It took me several hours of searching to finally find the Site URL. One of the biggest problems is that FB keeps changing this page. Solutions from the past couple years for this question vary, and none are accurate anymore. I'm posting this solution, which is accurate as of today, but I'm sure it'll be outdated soon as well.

Comment: That is completely unintuitive.  That button barely looks like a button, let alone indicating what lies beneath.

Answer (score 3):

Go to [Facebook Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) then edit the settings of your app.

Then under 'Select how your app integrates with Facebook' at the bottom, you can enter your site URL and so on.

Comment: The element in question is hidden... :/ I always need to remove the hidden_elem with chrome developer to change the url